# VBA 'For' syntax

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking at the excel exploit that can bypass the sheet protection in a matter of seconds.  They use a nested for loop similar to the first code snippet i was wondering if

This:

```
For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
    'code'   
Next: Next: Next:
```

is the same as this:

```
For i = 65 To 66
    For j = 65 To 66
         For k = 65 To 66
              'code'
         Next
    Next
Next
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, `:` can typically be used instead of a new line.

Comment: make it a answer and i will accept it if you want.

Comment: replace 'code' by `debug.print i, j, k` run both, and you will know.

Comment: Also worth noting if you are using Excel 2013 (or newer) this macro won't work since they've changed their sheet security.  See an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334365/password-cracker-of-protected-sheet-in-excel-using-vba/37334705#37334705).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same. One little difference though - the bottom snippet makes the nesting explicit.

The top snippet makes the code's indentation **lie about its real nesting level**, and violates an important coding principle:

> [...] Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. **Code for readability.**
>
> <sub>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/878436/1188513)</sub>

That code is basically "golfed" to be as short as possible, and to avoid looking like the outright ugly arrow code it really is.